# What to do if a question can be answered by combining two existing questions on the site?

Tags: discussion

Currently, there's a question here asking [who was killed to make Nagini a Horcrux](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123790/who-was-killed-to-make-nagini-a-horcrux-frank-bryce-or-bertha-jorkins). Now, we have a very obvious question that already answers that [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/who-did-voldemort-kill-to-create-the-horcruxes/23007#23007).

However, if you read through the entire body of the question, it's quite clear the person asking already knows that is a potential answer. To very, very briefly summarize, it seems to me that the asker is really trying to discover which source is more authoritative in this particular instance: *The Half-Blood Prince* or JKR in a Q&A session. Luckily, we have a pretty great question already asking that over [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117948/which-harry-potter-works-are-considered-canon) (although, it has multiple answers and the highest-voted answer isn't the one accepted).

Should we consider a question to be closed as a duplicate if it requires two separate answers from two different questions in order to completely answer the question? Or should the question stand alone and receive a proper answer that draws from the information contained in the two potential duplicate questions?

Comment: The highest voted answer isn't the accepted one due to a mixture of self-answering and merging questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we should **let the question be**.

Questions that can be answered by following the first link of a simple google search are closed.
But if it takes several links to read and summarize, then a question is legit, **even if the links to read and summarize belongs to Scifi.SE**

So a good answer to this particular question would provide the two links you did, with pertinent extracts from each explaining why you consider one source or the other more canon.